# Zabbix discovery: read JSON value

Tags: zabbix

I have discovery rule, which returns JSON document:

```
{
   "data":[
      {"SIZE":9556},
      {"SIZE_DIFFERENCE":0.00502302218501465},
      {"DUPLICATES":0},
      {"TODAY_ZERO_CLPRICE":9556},
      {"LISTED_SYMBOLS":true}
    ]
}
```

Can I assign values of this JSON objects to Item prototypes? Or handle it in triggers.
Like "If `SIZE` < 1 `Warning` will appear"

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON document in the question is not very valid for low-level discovery.

In that JSON, the `data` element has five objects, each with distinct attributes. Something like that would be more appropriate (note the LLD macro syntax):

```
{
   "data":[
      {
          "{#SIZE}":9556,
          "{#SIZE_DIFFERENCE}":0.00502302218501465,
          "{#DUPLICATES}":0,
          "{#TODAY_ZERO_CLPRICE}":9556,
          "{#LISTED_SYMBOLS}":true
      }
   ]
}
```

If you wish to create items with fixed values, you could probably create calculated items with a constant expression, like so:

```
{#SIZE}
```

However, a better approach would be to create trapper items during LLD and send those values separately.

Please see [official documentation on low-level discovery](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/discovery/low_level_discovery#creating_custom_lld_rules) and [trapper items](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/config/items/itemtypes/trapper) for more information.